# How to read HTTP Response Body?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I need to read the HTTP Response 200 OK with the following text/plain body. (Either one)

```
OK

NUMBER NOT IN LIST

ERROR
```

But I only know how to read the HTTP Response but not the response body. Explanation with example would be much appreciated

Comment: If you are *consuming* this, then it is presumably unrelated to asp.net. Frankly, isn't this just WebClient.DownloadString?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [WebClient.DownloadString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx) to make an HTTP GET request and get the HTTP response body as string returned:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string result = client.DownloadString("http://example.com/path/to/file");

    switch (result)
    {
        case "OK":
        case "NUMBER NOT IN LIST":
        case "ERROR":
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://example.com/path/to/file");

        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        if (request.Proxy == null)
        {
            request.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://example.com");
        }
        request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)(request.GetResponse());